# export to csv mongodb collection using mongoexport

Tags: windows, mongodb, csv, mongoexport

I'm trying to export all data from a collection of my mongoDB using mongodbexport. I'm following these syntax:

mongoexport --db mydb --collection mycollection --csv --out text.csv --fields NameColumn1,NameColumn2,NameColumn3,etc...

Running the code above, it creates only one file with the fieldnames and no values. If I just remove the --csv and change the out to text.txt, it exports all data.

Is there any other parameter that I'm missing?

Comment: Im confused about what the question is here, the parameters you specify look good to me and in fact worked in the test I just ran

Comment: It's really strange. Without the argument --csv it works fine! I don't know if it's a specific type that I'm storing the responsible for this bug.

Comment: So one thing that might explain this behavior: if there is a document that does not have a field in the list you provided, mongoexport will simply create an empty entry which will look like a row with no data in it.  Is this what you are seeing?  Have you tried exporting your data as csv and then importing with mongoimport?

Comment: Thanks for the help @ACE! I changed one type that was Guid to string and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right, the problem was the Guid Property. I changed to string and now it's working fine. I'll detail better the problem, cause it could help other people.

I'm using the Official MongoDB C# driver in my project. I installed through Nuget, and the current version is 1.8.0.

Here's the code I used to save:

```
public void Save(SampleModel model)
{
    var collection = _database.GetCollection<SampleModel>("SampleCollection");
    collection.Insert(model);
}
```

this Sample Model has this properties:

```
public Guid MyId { get; set; }
public DateTime InitProcess { get; set; }
public DateTime EndProcess { get; set; }
public string RuleName { get; set; }
public bool Match { get; set; }
public DateTime InitUpdate { get; set; }
public DateTime EndUpdate { get; set; }
```